# cannot install tradingWithPython into Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, conda

```
C:\Users\gaucho-ucsb>pip install tradingWithPython
Collecting tradingWithPython
Using cached tradingWithPython-3.1.0.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\gaucho~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-gshhyv\tradingWithPython\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tradingWithPython as twp
  File "tradingWithPython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .lib import extra
  File "tradingWithPython\lib\extra.py", line 20
    print('\r', self, end='')
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in      
c:\users\gaucho~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-gshhyv\tradingWithPython\
```

I'm trying to install the package tradingWithPython into anaconda but I keep getting this error which I can't figure out. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3 and is the module compatible?

Comment: Python 2.7 that comes with the Anaconda environment but it says on the website for this package that it should install for any version of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spoke with the author of the library and it seems that tradingwithPython only installs with Python3. It is not backwards compatible anymore.

I just tried this (because I had the same issue) and it seems to work now.

Comment: Thanks! This helped